# get the smallest unit of a currency in python

Tags: python

a credit card provider needs the transaction amount in cents or smallest available unit of the currency. since I want the code to be portable I have to get the smallest unit of a given currency and it's factor to the main unit. I've tried to get it from the locale module but i had no luck.

http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html

**Example**

i have a currency code as described in [iso 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)

EUR for Euro

then i need 1 Euro is 100 Eurocents (only the information 1/100, no text is needed)

according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sterling) there currencies which have more than 2 units like the old pund sterling

Comment: Could you give us please an example what you have and what you are expecting?

Comment: Judging by the upvotes, it must be clear to others what you're asking. However, I think this question could use an example

Comment: It looks like you'll have to compile your own table and keep it up to date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively cou can use following simple mapping module: http://pastebin.com/K7kVXi8P

Save this pastebin into a module within your project (e.g. simple_currency_helper.py) and use the map (or the helper method `get_currency_subunit`) to get out the currency subunit for a given ISO-Code.

```
>>> from simple_currency_helper import get_currency_subunit
>>> print get_currency_subunit('TND')
1000
```

Comment: this could work but i don't like the idea of maintaining this list in my code

Comment: Then :D feel free to make a real python project based on this pastebin (I'm not claiming entitlement to it) and commit this **a)** to a free bitbucket/githup or whatever resporitory so that the community can/will/may maintain it and **b)** finally upload the module result to the `python package index` (http://pypi.python.org/pypi) so that you also be able to use it comfortable in your code by including/updating with pypi packagemanagers (`easy_install`, `pip`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [python-money](http://code.google.com/p/python-money/) or [ccy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ccy) module.

Comment: i checked both of them and they provide a currency database but nothing about the currency's minor unit

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't an exiting module that will give you that information. However, all the data you need appears to be listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies

You'll probably need to maintain your own list (using the wikipedia page as the initial source). It would then be reasonably straight-forward to do your own mapping.

To get you started, here's a quick hack. Pasting and running the following script in your browser's Javascript console while on that wikipedia page will parse the content and append to the page a python-friendly version of the data:

```
var out = "data = {\n";
$("table.wikitable").find("tr").each(function(idx) {
    if (idx == 0) return;  // Skip first line.
    var last3 = $(this).find("td").slice(-3);
    var code = $(last3[0]).text();
    if (code != "None") {
        var scale = $(last3[2]).text().replace(",","");
        if (scale != "None") {
            var minor_name = $(last3[1]).text().split("[")[0];
            out += '  "' + code + '": ("' + minor_name + '", ' + scale + '),' + "\n";
        }
    }
});
out += "}";

$("<pre>").text(out).appendTo($("body"));
```

Here's an example output (script run using Firebug):

[image]

Here's the output: https://gist.github.com/16d43be2652a06cf962d

Answer (score 1):

The locale module of python can give you those informations, but only for the currency of the locale you're using, unfortunately it is not made to be multi-currencies.

[locale.localconv()](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.localeconv) can give you the informations for the current locale (the number of digits is the `'int_frac_digits'` member).
For example, if you're localized with en_US you can do this :

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, "en_US")  # set the en_US locale
locale.localeconv()['int_frac_digits']
>>> 2
locale.localeconv()['int_curr_symbol']
>>> 'USD '
```

But if you need to handle every currency, as the other said you'll have to make/maintain your table yourself.

Comment: has the only flaw that there are two currencies which are divided into 5 of the smaller unit. but I'll consider this solution since i python doesn't seem to support these locale settings

Comment: this answer isn't technically correct because of currencies which are divided into 5 of the next smaller unit. but i probably gona stick with this solution since the service i am including isn't supporting those currencies

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it exists for python. 
we used to work with this [xml](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51282547/xml/currency-list.xml).

```
<item code="USD" symbol="$" sort="20" iso="840">
<name lang="en">
  <singular>
    <nominative>US dollar</nominative>
    <genitive>US dollar</genitive>
    <dative>US dollar</dative>
    <full>US dollar</full>
    <prepos>US dollar</prepos>
  </singular>
  <plural>
    <nominative>US dollars</nominative>
    <genitive>US dollars</genitive>
    <dative>US dollars</dative>
    <full>US dollars</full>
    <prepos>US dollars</prepos>
  </plural>
</name>
<frac lang="en">100 cents</frac>
<bank href="http://www.federalreserve.gov/">
  <name lang="en">
    <nominative>The U.S. Federal Reserve System</nominative>
    <genitive>The U.S. Federal Reserve System</genitive>
  </name>
</bank>
<synonim lang="en">
  <item>buck</item>
  <item>green buck</item>
</synonim>
<banknotes/>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a few years, there is the [iso4217 package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso4217). It provides the ISO decimal point/base-10 exponent for the number of minor currency units per major currency unit:

```
>>> import iso4217
>>> iso4217.Currency(u'EUR').exponent
2
```

You can use it to convert directly between small and large currency:

```
def to_small_currency(large_currency_amount, iso_code):
    exponent = iso4217.Currency(iso_code).exponent
    if exponent == 0:  # 0 signals unused/nonexistent minor currency
        return large_currency_amount
    return large_currency_amount * (10 ** exponent)
```

Note that there are a few currencies which do not use base-10 for their minor currency. Currently, these are `MRU` and `MGA`. ISO 4217 still represents them with exponent 1, and the `iso4217` package does so as well.